# Xamarin Workbooks: Use of namespaces

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin

I want to try out [Xamarin Workbooks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/workbooks/). Thereby I choose `Console` with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

I get

> (3,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Isn't this namespace supported or what I'm doing wrong? I can't add a reference to System.Xml.dll only NuGet packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually reference assemblies via the **`#r`** instruction:

Example:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
var firstOneInList = (new List<string> {
    "foo", "foo2"
}).First<string>();
```

Try using `Load` instead:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\Users\some-user\Desktop\xmlResponse.txt‌​");
```

Comment: Now I don't get the above mentioned error anymore, but I'm still not able to use `XDocument`. E.g. `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\Users\some-user\Desktop\xmlResponse.txt");`. Do you know why? The error is a bit too long for a comment. *XmlException: Invalid data on root level. Row 1, Position 1. at void System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (Exception e) ...*. The text file works well in a normal console application.

Comment: Try using `Load` instead of `Parse`.

Comment: Sorry, I worked with `File.ReadAllText()` before and messed it up with `XDocument.Parse()`.